# Why is it that fewer threads finished than started in ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, executorservice

From my understanding, ExecutorService creates a pool of threads that can be reused. I created a pool size of 128 and had it execute 128 Runnable tasks. While it started 128 threads (by printing out "started"), only 10 printed out "finished".
Why is this occurring? Are finished threads being reused even as others are still in existence? Or is it that my threads simply are not finishing?

**EDIT:**
Added my code but I was unable to reproduce results. I did find, however that I would encounter a socketTimeoutException when I make too many accesses to the save website.

Below is an example of my code:

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Test {

static class TestConnection extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Started "+this.getName());
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        //System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
        System.out.println("Finished "+this.getName());
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(128);


    for(int i=0; i < 32;i++){
        TestConnection task = new TestConnection();
        pool.execute(task);
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    try {
        pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For the record: why exactly does your RunTask class extend **Thread**, instead of simply implementing Runnable?

Comment: Beyond that, we probably need a real [mcve]. What you are describing doesn't make sense - when the service starts the tasks, and they do print "start", sooner or later, all of them should print "finished" ... no matter what. So, in order to help you, you should enable us to somehow repro the issue.

Comment: Also, the code is buggy: while(i=0;i<128;i++) is not valid; main doesn't declare or catch exception from awaitTermination

Comment: I don't have much experience with multi threading so I extended Thread because it was part of a tutorial. In the original code I am creating WebDriver connections to different devices (given ip_addresses) on the LAN each of which have the same webpage and interact with those elements. I will see if I can create a reproduction and update shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i did tried above code i found exception.

```
Class not found com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindowListener
```

With exception handling it worked as expected. In order to resolve class not found error i added [htmlunit driver dependency](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver#htmlunitdriver) and it worked fine.

One of the missing thing in your code is you **need to quite driver** otherwise you may get websocket error running next time because earlier execution didn't terminated properly. Following is the working code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
   System.out.println("Started "+this.getName());
   try {
       WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
       driver.get("http://google.com");
       //System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
       driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
       driver.quit();
   } catch (Throwable e) {
       System.err.println(this.getName() + " " +e.getMessage());
   }
   System.out.println("Finished "+this.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It seems that the root cause of my problem are the socketTimeOutExceptions: read timeouts. It looks like I am improperly closing my drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `while` (which is invalid) to a `for` it works fine.

```
final int count = 128;
final boolean[] finished = new boolean[count];

class RunTask extends Thread {
    private final int i;

    public RunTask(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("start " + this.getName());
        //Do stuff. lots of I/O bound
        System.out.println("finished " + i);
        finished[i] = true;
    }
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(128);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        RunTask task = new RunTask(i);
        pool.execute(task);
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(!finished[i]) {
            System.out.println("NOT FINISHED! "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not print `NOT FINISHED`.